# Spring Boot: How to validate all parameters in a RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Say I have a `@RestController` with 10 methods, each of which takes one or more parameters. How can I tell Spring to validate each and every one of those parameters without annotating all of them with `@Valid`?

I already tried annotating the whole class with `@Validated` but to no effect. Maybe I have missed a necessary configuration?

The controller:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@Validated
@RestController
class EntityController {

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    fun update(@PathVariable id: UUID, @RequestBody entityDto: EntityDto) {
        // update the entity
    }

    // more methods
}
```

and the DTO:

```kotlin
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank

data class EntityDto(
    @field:NotBlank
    private val name: String
)
```

It works perfectly well if I add `@Valid` to the `@RequestBody` annotation at method level. Then requests like `PUT /123 { "name": "  " }` are rejected because of the blank `name` field.

Any clues as to how I get my controller to validate every object regardless of `@Valid` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class extending `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` and writing field validation logic for all the field inside it. Take a look at this example

https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints